# Swiper.js bugged: It knows that there are multiples slides but it doesn't let you navigate through them

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, swiper.js

I have some data coming from an API and I'm putting these data inside a slider using SwiperJS.
take a look at the code here:
[image]

As shown in the picture above. Whenever I navigate to web development/software development/UI design I load new data. The problem is, whenever I navigate to get the data, and loop through and display the data using swiper, swiper only shows me the first slide. Note that when I inspected the page I found all the slides there but the swiper for some reason is not displaying them.
here's the code:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of your code but the **actual** code.

Comment: My bad @kissu, I'll consider that next time.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. I had to create a function to force the rerendering of the swiper component. Here's the code:

```
forceRerenderSwiper() {
        // Remove my-component from the DOM
        this.renderComponent = false;

        // If you like promises better you can
        // also use nextTick this way
        this.$nextTick().then(() => {
            // Add the component back in
            this.renderComponent = true;
        });
    }
```

then you just add an if statement when you call the component

and don't forget to set the `renderComponent` to true when you're ready to render it.